# Document about calling webservice in jsf

Tags: web-services, jsf

I create a simple jsf page, i want to call webservice in jsf, but i can't find document which wrote about webservice in jsf. Can you give me some `link` about it? thank for your helping

Comment: It's not different in JSF backing bean from when doing in normal Java class. Ultimately, a JSF backing bean is also just a Java class. Just put/invoke same Java code in the desired place of JSF backing bean class (e.g. post construct or action method).

Comment: @BalusC Can you give me some link about it, because i don't know how it exactly is. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to call a published soap-WS (i.e: wsdl is online) inside your code you should create a ws-client for example with the wsimport tool (comes with JDK). this will give you a  java client that you can use to communicate with the WS (even an EJB will simplify your work). From the jsf perspective you are still using a Pojo, so, the client could be injected in a @ManagedBean.

About how to generate a ws-client: http://ayazroomy-java.blogspot.com/2013/07/using-wsimport-tool-to-generate-client.html